# unable to change owner for my drive

Tags: command-line, permissions

I am new to Ubuntu OS. I have noticed that once of my drive 480 GB drive partition is owned by root. I was trying to change the permission to user `skorlam` (my user name) but it says : `76386420-a1f6-46cf-9a78-c382383a4eb11`

here is my terminal output:

```
root@skorlam:/media/skorlam/76386420-a1f6-46cf-9a78-c382383a4eb11/Oracle# chown -R skorlam 76386420-a1f6-46cf-9a78-c382383a4eb11
chown: cannot access ‘76386420-a1f6-46cf-9a78-c382383a4eb11’: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

```
chown -R skorlam:skorlam /media/skorlam/76386420-a1f6-46cf-9a78-c382383a4eb11/
```

Will do the trick!

**What was wrong:**

The problem was that you were giving a relative path to the chown command. As this will work when your working path is the right one, containing the path you want to work on all will work fine.

More about local and absolute paths can be found [here](http://www.linuxnix.com/abslute-path-vs-relative-path-in-linuxunix/).

In your case you were at `/media/skorlam/76386420-a1f6-46cf-9a78-c382383a4eb11/Oracle` and tried to work with this path `76386420-a1f6-46cf-9a78-c382383a4eb` which of course does not exist in the current working directory.

I suggest always using the absolute path when doing file operations like `rm` `cp` `mv` `chown` `chmod` etc. to avoid conflicts.

The second thing I added to your command was `skorlam:skorlam` (the name again after the colon) this means that the files and directorys belong to you user as well as to your users group, chown syntax is `chown [OPTIONS] user:group`.